# Не удается получить доступ к атрибутам родительского класса Python

Tags: python, ооп, классы, tkinter

При попытке использования атрибутов родительского класса получаю ошибку `AttributeError`, не могу разобраться в чем причина.

```
class MainMenu:
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window

        title = Label(self.window,text = 'Хрестики-нулики', font=("Comic Sans MS",24,'bold'))
        title.pack()
        choose = Label(self.window,text = 'Виберіть режим гри', font=("Comic Sans MS",16))
        choose.pack()
        self.window.geometry('600x400')
        two_players = Button(self.window,text= 'Два гравця')
        bot = Button(self.window,text= 'Компьютер')
        line = Button(self.window,text= 'Лінія')
        coins = Button(self.window,text= 'Очки')
        two_players.place(x= 360, y = 140)
        bot.place(x= 180, y = 140)
        line.place(x= 360, y = 180)
        coins.place(x= 180, y = 180)
        self.players = 1
        self.mode = 'line'
        self.on_start_game = None
        two_players.bind("<Button-1>",self.two_players)
        line.bind("<Button-1>",self.line)
        coins.bind("<Button-1>",self.points)


    def two_players(self,event):
        self.players = 2 
        print(self.players)


    def points(self,event):
        self.mode = 'points'
        self.window.destroy()
        root.deiconify()
        game = Game_line(self.players)
    def line(self,event):
        self.mode = 'line'
        self.window.destroy()
        game = Game_line(self.players)
        root.deiconify()

menu = MainMenu(welcome_window)


class Game_line(MainMenu):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        self.mode = 0
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.game_run = True
        self.cross_count = 0
        self.field = []
        self.player_num = 0
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 195, in <module>
    game = Game_line()
  File "main.py", line 68, in __init__
    super().__init__(parent)
  File "main.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.window.geometry('600x400')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'geometry'
```

Comment: Добавьте код, как у вас создается объект Game_line или MainMenu. Скорее всего при создании MainMenu вы параметром передаете None вместо окна.

Comment: Добавил, Game_line создается в методах MainMenu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо:

```
self.players = 1
Game_line(self.players) 

-> вызов Game_line(1)

class Game_line(MainMenu):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        self.mode = 0
        super().__init__(parent)

-> вызов MainMenu.__init__(1)
-> MainMenu.self.window = 1
-> 1.geometry('600x400') ???
```

`Game_line` явно не предполагалось инициализировать числом игроков, там должно быть родительское окно.
Но вообще, судя по ошибке, вы где-то ещё раньше используете `Game_line` вообще без параметров.